# OnDisconnectAsync is not working...?

Tags: c#, android, android-asynctask, signalr

I am following [these guidelines](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx).

But problem is appeared when I try to override Task `OnDisconnectAsync` of `PersistentConnection` class. Code as bellows:

```
public class MyConnection:PersistentConnection
{
......
protected override Task OnDisconnectAsync(string clientId)
{
  //1. Remove clientID from <List> memberManager
  Member member = (from m in memberManager where m.clientID == clientId select m).FirstOrDefault();
  memberManager.Remove(member);
  return Connection.Broadcast(new { type = 1, value = "Disconneted ClientID" + clientId });
  }
......

}
```

I find out that when user close tab or browser, the `OnDisconnectAsync` Task do not fire.

What is wrong in my code or how do i know disconnected client?

Answer (score 0):

What webserver are you using (IIS, IISExpress or Cassini)? If using IIS or IISExpress isconnect will fire but it isn't immediate (it varies per web server and cassini never fires disconnect), we're making some changes to improve responsiveness in the next version.

Comment: Thank dfowler. ! I am using IISExpress and could you give more information about this problem. How long this event will be fired after connections broken..??

Comment: Are you using the latest package on nuget? If so, I've seen it take around ~15 seconds sometimes for detect a disconnect. It can take longer theoretically but I haven't seen it much in practice.